# Django installed,but "startapp" occured ImportError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django

I uninstalled Django1.9 and install Django1.8.14

I successfully installed Django1.8.14 by confirm "import django""django.VERSION" in the python command line.
[image: error report]

I use python 3.5

Comment: Did you confirm the versions using say `pip freeze` and `python --version`?

Comment: @Jedi yes,I confirm by pip freeze

Comment: Can you please attach output of these commands: `python --version`, `pip --version`, `pip freeze`

Comment: python --version Python 3.5.2               Python 3.5.2         Django==1.8.14

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I solved the problem by switching the python35-intel32bit to python35-amd64 and pip install Django1.9.
By the way,I run it on Win10-intel-64bit.